# Writing an interpreter in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, interpreter, ml

I'm following a course in my University that ask me to write an interpreter in OCaml of a language starting from its operational semantics. Unfortunately, they didn't give us much resources from which we can learn about it, except from the lesson's slides. Can someone suggest me some book or some website where I can find something about it (or similar) ? 
Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "it"? OCaml, or operational semantics? For OCaml you can find resources at http://ocaml.org/learn/. I don't have a handy ref for operational semantics, but I see good ideas when I just Google for it.

Comment: The problem is not the Ocaml language, but the way how you use it to make an interpeter on a given semantics.

Comment: Well, an operational semantics is called that because it consists of a set of "before" and "after" pictures for the objects in a universe. Your interpreter looks for "before" structures and translates them into the "after" form. If you keep doing this you get an answer. Do you have a given representation for the semantics? That will be the real essence of the problem.

Comment: Yes I have, the problem is to make an interpreter over the semantics, and this interpreter has to be written in Ocaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you should try [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) by B. Pierce  which is probably a good reference on the topic (especially if your input language is functional).

If you want to go deeper into semantics I would advice [Formal Semantics of Programming Languages](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/formal-semantics-programming-languages) by G. Winskel. But it won't help you with implementation.

Finally, if at one point you need to compile your language instead of interpreting it you should have a look at [Modern Compiler Implementation in ML](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/ml/) by A. Appel.

But these books are probably overkills for what you want to do (your lectures notes should probably be enough).

Comment: I'm reading the first book you suggested me and I'm find it very useful, thanks a lot

Comment: I would also recommend exactly Pierce's and Appel's books. Appel's was my first compiler book and I think it is a bit difficult to read compared to e.g. [Basics of Compiler Design](http://www.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/) by Torben Mogensen (free book).

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a suitable data type that represents the language, it's mostly a matter of translating the semantics, rule by rule, using pattern-matching.

For instance, given this trivial language that has integer literals, addition, and assignable variables:

```
type Expression = Literal of int | Variable of string | Addition of Expression * Expression;;
type Statement = Assignment of string * Expression | Sequence of Statement * Statement;;
```

and a Store for storing the values of variables:

```
type Store = <something>
lookup : Store -> string -> int
update : Store -> string -> int -> Store
```

we could define semantic functions like these (I'll skip the step of defining the semantics formally):

```
let semE store = function
   | Literal l -> l
   | Variable x -> lookup store x
   | Addition e1 e2 -> (semE e1 store) + (semE e2 store);;

let semS store = function
   | Assignment x e -> update store x (semE e store)
   | Sequence (s1, s2) -> let store' = semS store s1 
                          in semS store' s2;;
```

This is a complete interpreter for the language, but it doesn't have a parser for translating from the language's syntax to the representation above.

For instance,

```
semS (Sequence (Assignment "x" (Literal 3), 
                Assignment "x" (Addition (Variable "x") (Literal 1)))) 
      empty_store
```

which might be represented in the input language as `x := 3; x := x + 1`, should result in a `Store` where `x` has the value `4`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it was very clear, but they ask me to do interpreter more and more bigger, so that, I'd like to know if exist one book or place where I can find something longer and more accurate about it.. How did you manage to learn to do all this stuff?

Comment: @GiovanniMauro The principle is exactly the same with a bigger interpreter - define your language representation and what a program's state is if it needs one (the Store above), then implement one semantic rule at a time according to the definition. It's very difficult to say anything specific without knowledge of "your" language, but one important thing to learn is to not try and do too much at once.

Comment: @GiovanniMauro one possible (free) book is [Semantics with Applications](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~bra8130/Wiley_book/wiley.html). They use Miranda as the implementation language, which is very similar to Haskell or ML.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this MOOC (in english !) : [ocamlmooc](https://www.france-universite-numerique-mooc.fr/)

Books (the ones I use... but there is many other) :
[Developping applications with Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/index.html)
[real world ocaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/index.html).

In the first book, have a look on [Chapter 6](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora058.html), that should held you.

Comment: Hi,maybe I can't open well the first link, because it shows me an home of some videolessons.. I had a look on the chapter 6 you posted but it is too short for helping me..

Comment: the first link is indeed video lessons on Ocaml - but may be I have not understood very well your request when I posted this answer - I understood that you had only slides on Ocaml.... It turns out that it is more on interpreter that you are looking for some help.

Comment: Yes, the central problem is to write the interpreter, in the specific it has to be written in Ocaml.