# Ocaml interpreter first approach

Tags: ocaml, interpreter

I have to create an interpreter in ocaml, I have to implement ths String and some operation on it. Something like `strcpy` in `c` . I never use ocaml, I googled a lot but I can't find something that helps me. So I have to write the synthax?
Something like :

```
type ide = string
type exp = ........ EXPRESSIONS
```

Then some module, `struct` in c ? And some SEMANTIC EVALUATION FUNCTIONS ? Sorry is my first time in ocaml, but also my first interpreter, I want to learn it so I need just some input to know where to study it . Please don't rate me wrong I wanna learn!

Comment: You say you *have* to write an interpreter, so, unless you were somehow hired for a job that you're completely unprepared for, I assume this means you're attending a course on that subject. Presumably this course's study materials are a good place to start.

Comment: @sepp2k it's for university course but we havn't enough materials, we have jut something for ocaml, nothing about interpreter

Comment: some BASIC interpreter : https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora058.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing an interpreter in OCaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120459/writing-an-interpreter-in-ocaml)